# ng-keydown doesn't work in angular

Tags: angularjs, keydown

I try to bind arrow keydown event to the document, but it doesn't work in angular.
code:

```
function CubeCtrl($scope, $locale) {

$scope.click = function(){
    alert("click")
}
$scope.keydown = function(){
    alert("keydown")
}
```

}

html:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="CubeCtrl" ng-click="click()" ng-keydown="keydown()">
```

and here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sYAwC/1/)

Comment: It works fine with the unstable version of Angularjs which is a release candidate already. Here is your fiddle with it http://jsfiddle.net/ranru/sYAwC/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably Angular version issue.

You can chcek this solution: [UI Utils](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)

Or best way is to write your own directive for this event:

**Directive:**

```
   var mod = angular.module('mydirectives');
mod.directive('ngKeydown', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
             // this next line will convert the string
             // function name into an actual function
             var functionToCall = scope.$eval(attrs.ngKeydown);
             elem.on('keydown', function(e){
                  // on the keydown event, call my function
                  // and pass it the keycode of the key
                  // that was pressed
                  // ex: if ENTER was pressed, e.which == 13
                  functionToCall(e.which);
             });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-keydown="onKeydown">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ngKeydown` directive is not supported by version 1.1.1. You should be using atleast version 1.1.2 for using this directive.